How to make a local llm call a tool in langchain?
I have the following code:
from langchain_community.tools.tavily_search import TavilySearchResults
from IPython.display import Image, display
from PIL import Image
from langchain import hub
from langchain_core.prompts import ChatPromptTemplate
from langchain.callbacks.streaming_stdout import StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, SystemMessage
from langchain_community.chat_models import ChatLlamaCpp
from langchain.callbacks.manager import CallbackManager
from langchain.agents import create_tool_calling_agent, AgentExecutor
from langchain.agents import AgentType
from langgraph.prebuilt import create_react_agent

search = TavilySearchResults(max_results=2)
tools = [search]

model = ChatLlamaCpp(

  #LLAMA3.1-8B-Q4_K_M
  model_path="/home/s1ngle/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--bartowski--Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct-GGUF/snapshots/9a8dec50f04fa8fad1dc1e7bc20a84a512e2bb01/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B-Instruct-Q4_K_M.gguf",

  n_gpu_layers=0,
  n_threads=8,
  n_batch=8,
  n_ctx=8192,
  max_tokens=4096,
  seed=-1,
  f16_kv=True,
  verbose=False,
  cache=False,
  echo=False,
  temperature=0,
  top_k=10,
  top_p=0.95,
  streaming=True,
  callbacks=CallbackManager([StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()]),
  model_kwargs={
    "chat_format": "llama-3"
  },
)
graph = create_react_agent(model, tools)
graph.invoke({"messages": [
  HumanMessage(content="whats the weather in san francisco?")
]})

It prints the following result:
However, I'm a large language model, I don't have real-time access to current weather conditions.
But I can suggest some ways for you to find out the current weather in San Francisco:
1. **Check online weather websites**: You can check websites like AccuWeather, Weather.com, or the National Weather Service (NWS) website.
2. **Use a mobile app**: You can download mobile apps like Dark Sky, Weather Underground, or The Weather Channel to get real-time weather updates.
3. **Tune into local news**: You can watch local news channels in San Francisco to get the latest weather forecast.
I hope this helps you find out the current weather in San Francisco!

As you can see despite having tavily tool it has not been called for some reason. I tried to implement this with other llm - gemma2. But the result is the same. Why ?

I think automatic tool choice resp. calling is not available for it: https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/discussions/23288

@UninformedUser Thank you very much. You are totally right ! Don't you know how to make it use tools automatically ?

@UninformedUser By the way, you can post your comment as an answer. I will accept it

You are missing the prompt template in create_react_agent which should contain the tool definition.
Prompt:

    The prompt must have input keys:
        * `tools`: contains descriptions and arguments for each tool.
        * `tool_names`: contains all tool names.
        * `agent_scratchpad`: contains previous agent actions and tool outputs as a string.

definition:
def create_react_agent(
    llm: BaseLanguageModel,
    tools: Sequence[BaseTool],
    prompt: BasePromptTemplate,
    output_parser: Optional[AgentOutputParser] = None,
    tools_renderer: ToolsRenderer = render_text_description,
    *,
    stop_sequence: Union[bool, List[str]] = True,
) -> Runnable:


Your create_react_agent you are talking about is legacy and a part of langchain API but mine is a part of langgraph have another definition: https://langchain-ai.github.io/langgraph/how-tos/create-react-agent/

I see. I think you need to pass a system prompt to tell it to use tools as messages for graph. the 3rd parameter in your create_react_agent call.
create_react_agent(model, tools, state_modifier=system_message)
get the sample here: https://python.langchain.com/docs/how_to/migrate_agent/#prompt-templates

I tried. It didn't solve the issue
